# How do I change the default browser that konsole opens URLs with?

Tags: google-chrome, default-programs, default-browser, konsole

I have google-chrome set as my default web browser in Ubuntu and gnome applications.   However, when using **konsole**, all links open in konqueror, and not google-chrome!

I've tried setting the default browser with: `sudo update-alternatives --config 'x-www-browser'`

This works for opening links in gnome-terminal, and other gnome programs... but not kde ones like konsole.  Also, there appears to be no kcontrol program for accessing the kde settings.

Does anyone know a way to set the kde setting for this while still using gnome?

EDIT: From what I can tell, I've got all the related settings configured that I can think of...

```
grep 'chrome' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
application/x-extension-htm=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-html=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-shtml=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xhtml=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xht=google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop

grep 'chrome' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

text/html=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
text/xml=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
application/xhtml_xml=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=google-chrome.desktop
```

And there are no references to konqueror:

```
grep -i 'konqueror' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
grep -i 'konqueror' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
grep -i 'kon' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
grep -i 'kon' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Comment: Try exporting BROWSER variable. `export BROWSER=google-chrome`

Comment: @Capt.Nemo : Hmm... still opens with Konqueror

Comment: I have the same problem with Debian Squeeze.

Comment: i dont know why, but I have another `mimeapps.list` at `~/.config`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into this problem running konsole in Ubuntu/Unity. When everything else failed, I edited `~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`:

```
[General]
BrowserApplication[$e]=!google-chrome
```

Logout, login -- bingo!

Comment: Although njsg's answer did work for the most part to fix default browser when performing many actions which launch it on the desktop.  It appears that `konsole` and apps which use it such as `yakuake` look for this setting in `~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`.  After reviving the old system plagued by this issue, I can accept this answer with confidence!

Comment: I had to add this to ~/.config/kdeglobals instead.

Comment: I come here on Ubuntu 16.04 using Yakuake and this was the answer I needed in order to open links from within the console (Yakuake/Konsole) through Chrome.

Comment: If you use chromium rather than chrome use "chromium-browser" rather than "google-chrome"

Comment: what does the exclamation mark `!` signify?

Comment: @andrybak I'm not 100% sure but, I think it signifies it's a command. There is no `!`  when using google-chrome.desktop, for example. I'm wondering what `[$e]` means, however, as it's not added to this line when I use the system settings in Manjaro to set the default browser.

Answer (score 19):

The problem with "default applications" nowadays is that different programs look for the defaults in different ways. What we can call the traditional approach is `$BROWSER` and `mailcap` files.

But, recently, many graphical programs have started relying on `.desktop` files, and there is a set of `xdg-*` tools devoted to manipulate and retrieve some of the defaults.

Try:

```
xdg-settings get default-web-browser
```

If this shows konqueror, then

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop
```

Should fix it, at least if the `xdg-settings` documentation is to be trusted.

Now, all that `xdg-settings` does is talking with the currently running desktop environment, so this should be `GNOME`, and it should be already set to `google-chrome`...

Answer (score 8):

This is the correct behavior of **Konsole**. It opens links in the KDE default browser. If no browser is specified, it will launch **Konqueror**. Since you could not find any mentioning of **Konqueror** in the configuration files, the latter is exactly your case.

To set your preferred browser do the following (I assume that your **Konsole** and **Konqueror** are from **KDE4**):

- open KDE System Settings (e.g. by launching **Kcontrol**)
- navigate to **Default Applications** (it must be somewhere under "Workspace Appearance")
- find the **Web Browser** section
- write the [path and] name of your preferred browser

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using Gnome as my default desktop, but have installed Konsole & kdelibs.  I can't find the `kcontrol` binary on my system, so it must not be installed.

Comment: @TrinitronX the executable is now `systemsettings` (packagename the same)

Comment: it was opening a zip file in GEdit (buggy of course)!!! see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/896564/when-clicking-an-url-to-a-zip-file-at-yakuake-konsole-opens-gedit-how-to-chang

Comment: This answer worked for me. Newer KDE versions even allow you to select from installed browsers via a dropdown menu. Konsole then uses the selected browser.

Answer (score 1):

The right way for me to make this work in ubuntu 18.04 was to add

```
[General]
BrowserApplication[$e]=!put-your-favorite-browser-here
```

to `~/.config/kdeglobals` as [suggested here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=800502#37). After that you only need to start a new konsole.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using 'Default Applications'. Simply search the name in the start menu to find the window.

[image: KDE Dialog: Default Applications]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page: http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Default_Applications

There is a kde system default settings application. However, since your in gnome, check out this file:

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

In addition look in here:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Remove any references to konqueror.

Comment: Hmm... very strange. I look in those files and I've got no references to konqueror at all. Instead, for all the html & xhtml related mimetypes, it's set to firefox & chrome. Note that I've tried with both "Konqueror" and the "Yakuake" terminal which appears to use Konsole underneath. @Jorge Castro: See my edited question above for the applicable settings I have in these files.