# Clicking an url or a zip file in yakuake/konsole, opens gedit! How to change that?

Tags: url, yakuake

The url was to a remote zip file, for example

[image]

`xdg-settings get default-web-browser` gives `chromium-browser.desktop`, so "any?" url should be opened at chromium, not GEdit...

My default zip opener in nautilus is "archive manager", not GEdit...

Even worse: in GEdit, it will not even download the file first, it will open inside GEdit (of course) as an uneditable binary file, and will still open it remotely, and if I try to save it seems to try to save remotely too (now that becomes a problem as I didnt intend to do that ever!) :(

What is happening? How can I fix it?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04, and the highest version of yakuake (the one I am using) on it is 2.9.9-1 to the date.
Konsole also at latest 4.13.3.

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62182/how-do-i-change-the-default-browser-that-konsole-opens-urls-with?rq=1

Comment: @ElderGeek solved! this is the right answer there http://askubuntu.com/a/142044/46437, but kde is bugged because the default option was "in an application based on the contents of the url" and that called GEdit, so I changed it to `opera` and it worked. My question is related to that one, but not specifically, so I believe ppl having problems with links that are zip files may still find my question useful. Not 100% sure tho, what you think? may be this one could be a duplicate? btw I have konqueror and it still called GEdit.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. It is indeed a duplicate, but fear not this question will still act as  a signpost pointing people with your exact problem in the right direction.